# CROSSTAB and PIVOT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table -

```
org_id  et  rt         level     diagnosis   count
9453    2   AGENCY     SERVICE   MMTA    18
9453    1   PHYSICIAN  SERVICE   M_WOUND     5
9453    1   REFERRER   SERVICE   M_WOUND 5
9453    1   REFERRER   SERVICE   N_WOUND 5
```

How do I pivot this table such that -

```
org_id  et  rt         level     MMTA  M_WOUND   N_WOUND
9453    2   AGENCY     SERVICE   18   
9453    1   PHYSICIAN  SERVICE         5
9453    1   REFERRER   SERVICE   0     5         5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select org_id, et, rt, level,
       max(count) filter (where diagnosis = 'MMTA') as mmta,
       max(count) filter (where diagnosis = 'M_WOUND') as m_wound,
       max(count) filter (where diagnosis = 'N_WOUND') as n_wound
from t
group by org_id, et, rt, level;
```